# List Taxonomy terms in search result

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, search

By default search results show title, snippet, author details, date and content type in the listing so the next logical step would be what tags / categories... However I have been totally unable to find any details on the subject.

In search-result.tpl.php I would like to list each nodes taxonomy terms, how is this possible?

Not really worried about the output of the terms but would just like the terms available as a array within the template.

Comment: In my question (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/137271/34116) there is an answer for this.