# Undefined index: und on search-result.tpl.php for Taxonomy Terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I want to show the node title and related taxonomy terms in a table and modifying the search-result.tpl.php to do this.

What I use to for taxonomy terms is that:

```
<td class="field-item">
<?php
    $str = '';
    foreach($result['node']->field_my_taxonomy_term['und'] as $obj) 
        $str .= l($obj['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $obj['tid']) . ',&nbsp;';
    print trim($str, ',&nbsp;');
?>
</td>
```

This code works in one of my Drupal website and **doesn't work** on another one and gives this error:

```
Notice: include() (.../search-result.tpl.php  line 20) Undefined index: und.
Warning: include() (.../search-result.tpl.php  line 20) Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
```

How can I show the taxonomy terms related to the node in search-result.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either that your field has a set language (not `'und'` which stands as 'undefined') or that you have no value for `field_my_taxonomy_term`.

Either way you should add this control before your foreach (I also rewrite it to fit [Drupal best practices](https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards)) :

```
<td class="field-item">
  <?php $str = ''; ?>
  <?php if (isset($result['node']->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && $result['node']->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE]): ?>
    <?php foreach ($result['node']->field_my_taxonomy_term[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $obj): ?>
      <?php $str .= l($obj['taxonomy_term']->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $obj['tid']) . ',&nbsp;'; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php print trim($str, ',&nbsp;'); ?>
  <?php endif ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @pbonnefoi . **It's working correctly now**. I had tried the [LANGUAGE_NONE] instead of ['und'] but it didn't work. Interesting...
And also, thanks for the (Drupal best practices) link.

Comment: Cool i'm glad that helped you.